# Android: How to pass object to new start activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-markers, android-dialog

Currently I'm working on make google map marker on click info window connect to wifi,so i have a custom alert-dialog activity to login access point,from that dialog activity, i need call back connection method with a marker parameter,How can i pass Marker m parameter to the new activity, if i want to call `wificonnector(m)` in that new class? seems `putextra` not working here

```
public void wificonnector(Marker marker) 
        {...}

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker m) {

Intent i = new Intent(myMap.this, ConnectDialog.class);
i.putExtra("marker",m);                  
startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need ssid in your `ConnectDialog`, why not send that value instead of the whole `Marker`?

```
Intent i = new Intent(myMap.this, ConnectDialog.class);
String ssid = m.getSnippet(); // or title, depending on where you store ssid
i.putExtra("ssid",ssid);
startActivity(i);
```

`Marker` objects should be treated like `View` objects. If you try to send them outside their context, they cause memory leaks.

Comment: I'm changing a way to do this, because what i need is ssid, so i create a local variable string to marker.gettitle(), and pass that string to dialog activity, it should be working, your recommend is just like what i do, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because Intents are using a [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to provide data to another Activity you can't put a Marker in the Extras. The Marker class doesn't use the Parcelable or Serializable interface, which is needed to put an Object into the Bundle.

But you can put the `MarkerOptions` into it and make a new Marker in your ConnectDialog class.

Comment: create a new marker? because my marker is based on which one i click, from ConnectDialog class, how can i know which marker i click. I need using that specific marker get ssid and connect

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities.

Very popular is to set the static variable in the code like:

```
ConnectDialog.marker = marker;    
Intent i = new Intent(myMap.this, ConnectDialog.class);
i.putExtra("marker",m);                  
startActivity(i);
```

However using such static variables is very quick - then the readebility of code seems to be not very clear, mostly in big apps. Such kind of architecture seems to be smelly a little bit.

Other possibility is to get the custom class that is "Serializable" and push it by the intent extras. Such example could be MarkerOptions or any other custom class.

Comment: Using `static` variable is as wrong as it is quick. When application process is in background and killed, you end up with `NullPointerException`s on returning to the `ConnectDialog`. I advide against using `static`s.